# Method Not Recognized

Tags: c#, wpf

This code I am working on is not working properly. It displays this error when hello() is invoked:

> nameThisString "does not exist in the current context"

I have the overall code structure (it's simplified greatly to get to the point). What is wrong with my code?

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Application3
{
    public partial class MainView : UserControl
    {
        public SecondClass secondClass;
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            hello();    
        }

        private void hello()
        {
            secondClass.nameThisString("hello");
        }        
    }

    public class SecondClass
    {
        public void nameThisString(string what)
        {
            what = "me";
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Maybe you simplified too much? ([ideone](http://ideone.com/yCCnuv))

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't display the problem you've claimed. Please produce a [mcve].

Comment: I'm with @UweKeim. Does this simplified version actually still reproduce your problem? I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: The only thing this code will produce is a `NullReferenceException` - you've never instantiated `SecondClass`.

Comment: You declare secondClass, but you never instantiate it.  Maybe if you did 'public SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass()'

Comment: This is literally the exact code that I am using.

Comment: Sorry it's giving me the error "Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Sorry I am new, but doesn't "public SecondClass secondClass;" create an instance?

Comment: Well that's a completely different error! It's an exception rather than the compile-time error you talked about before.

Comment: And no, it doesn't. It declares a field, which has a default value of `null`.

Comment: @Sean Nope, declaring the variable doesn't create an instance of that class.

Comment: I was getting both errors. The first was before I compiled and the next was while it was trying to compile. @ChrisF, how are declaring and creating an instance different? Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Per your posted code, there is only one way you can get the said error; if you have called your method like below instead of `secondClass.nameThisString("hello");`

```
    private void hello()
    {
        nameThisString("hello");
    }
```

Per your comment you are getting a `NullRef` exception cause you have just defined the variable but haven't created an instance for it. change your code to be like

```
    public SecondClass secondClass;
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        secondClass = new SecondClass(); // create an instance
        hello();    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between defining a variable and creating an instance? IE why would you just define it and not create it?

Comment: if you say `int a` you are just defining or declaring a int variable but creating a instance is nothing but when you assign a value for it and say `a = 100`. though INT is value type ... for a reference type like class `SecondClass secondClass` you have just declared the variable and it's null right now (or) doesn't point to any object in heap and so you will have to create a instance by using the `new` operator. Consider learning about OOP more first.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Rahul `int` is perhaps the worst example you could have given - `int a` *does* give it a value (`0`) due to its type. Classes behave differently.

Comment: @Jamiec, that's kind a for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an instance of the SecondClass in the constructor of the MainView class first.

Comment: In your constructor - `secondClass = new SecondClass()`

Comment: This wouldn't cause the error mentioned - would be a null ref ...

Comment: @PaulB which is actually the problem (as revealed in the comments)

Comment: True - though I commented before that was revealed ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to instantiate the class; use like this:

```
 public SecondClass secondClass;
 public MainView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    SecondClass = new SecondClass();
    hello();
  }
```

Or simply:

```
public SecondClass secondClass=new SecondClass();
```